# Restoring failed Informix mirror chunk

Tags: informix

What should be done if an Informix mirror chunk failed and needs to be replaced with new chunk?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, examples of your work. I think the majority of users are happy to help, but not do your work for you.

Comment: Is the replacement chunk going to have the same path and offset as the original, preferably via a symlink?  Or do you need to give it a new name and offset?  It is harder if you need to use a new name.  The names you specify to Informix should normally be symlinks so that you can change where they point without needing to rebuild things.

Answer (score 1):

One command that you could use is `onspaces`.  Run by a DBSA with no arguments, the help output includes the information:

```
onspaces -m <spacename> { -p <path> -o <offset> -m <path> <offset> [-y] |
                          -f <filename> } 
onspaces -r <spacename> [-y]
onspaces -s <spacename> -p <path> -o <offset> {-O | -D} [-y]
```

- `-m` — Add mirroring to an existing DBspace, PLOGspace, BLOBspace or 
        SBLOBspace
- `-r` — Turn mirroring off for a DBspace, PLOGspace, BLOBspace or SBLOBspace
- `-s` — Change the status of a chunk

#### Managing mirroring for a complete dbspace

Clearly, you could turn mirroring off for the down chunk (with `-r`) and then turn it back on with `-m`.  You should investigate the [Administrator's Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/adref.htm) — especially the section on [ON-Spaces](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0460.htm) — and maybe the [Administrator's Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/admin.htm) too.

The ON-Spaces section on mirroring contains the note:

> The mirrored chunks should be on a different disk. You must mirror all the chunks at the same time.

and the syntax diagram allows multiple occurrences of the `-p <path> -o <offset> -m <path> <offset>` part of the synopsis.  The `-p` and `-o` portions identify the existing chunk, and the `-m` portion identifies the new mirror chunk.

The `-f` option allows you to put the per-chunk information into a text file.

This technique has the not necessarily desirable side-effect of dropping all mirroring on the affected dbspace temporarily, and then reinstating it.

#### Managing single mirror chunks

Further research reveals a way to recover a single chunk at a time.  The Administrator's Guide has a section on:

- [Fault tolerance](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1162.htm)

with sub-sections:

- [Mirroring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0794.htm)
- [Using mirroring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0816.htm)

These cover the theory and practice of mirroring.  In particular, you seem to need:

- [Take down a mirror chunk using `onspaces`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0841.htm)

  ```
  onspaces -s db_acct -p /dev/mirror_chk1 -o 0 -D
  ```
- [Recover a mirror chunk using `onspaces`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0844.htm)

  ```
  onspaces -s db_acct -p /dev/mirror_chk1 -o 0 -O
  ```

This allows you to specify the chunk that is down — if the system has not already marked it down.  And you can then bring it back online (into recovery mode) when you've replaced the physical media.  As noted in a comment, this is much easier when you use symlinks to name the device (file) that holds the data (and if you don't use non-zero offsets; for the most part, they're a relic from the days when big disk drives were 100 MiB or less).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your reply. It will help me to know more about Informix DBA issues and resolutions. :)